# How to count rows after a specific row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a contact mechanism between my website's users *(always between **two** users)*. User A (sender) can send a message to users B (receiver) based on two rules:

1. User A could send 2 messages utmost to user B and he must receive at least one message from user B to be able to send another 2.
2. User A could send 4 messages utmost  to everybody in daily period, not more.

And here is my table structure:

```
-- contact
+----+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------------+
| id | sender_id | receive_id |          message         |  date_time |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------------+
| 1  | 123       | 456        | Hi, how are you?         | 1492431111 |
| 2  | 123       | 789        | How are you doing?       | 1492431112 |
| 3  | 456       | 789        | Why would you say that?  | 1492431113 |
| 4  | 123       | 456        | Why don't you answer?    | 1492431114 |
| 5  | 789       | 456        | Because the sky is high  | 1492431115 |
| 6  | 123       | 789        | Hello?                   | 1492431116 | 
+----+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------------+
```

And here is my current query:

```
INSERT INTO contact(sender_id, receive_id, message, date_time )
SELECT ?, ?, ?, unix_timestamp()
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT count(*) AS num_day,
    FROM contact
    WHERE user_id = ?
      AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 day))
    HAVING num_day > 4
)
```

As you can see, only the second rule is implemented in my query. How can I also implement the first rule to the query?

Comment: In general, if you speak about rows *after* a row, you must have them sorted by some column. So you can count relevant rows that have the value in this column larger (or smaller) than the value of this column in the said row.

Comment: @JiriTousek You mean I need to add one more column? I'm ok with that. If you think it's the solution, please write an answer

Comment: No, I mean that you probably sorted the rows by some column when thinking about "after". So you can compare the value in this column to find out whether the rows are "before" or "after" it, and count just rows "after" it.

Answer (score 0):

Query to find out number of messages from 'A' to 'B' since their last reply:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM contact
WHERE sender_id = 'A'
  AND receive_id = 'B'
  AND date_time > (
    SELECT max(date_time)
    FROM contact
    WHERE sender_id = 'B'
      AND receive_id = 'A'
    )
```

Note this will probably not work if there's no message from 'B' to 'A' yet - you'll have to modify the query to account for that.

Comment: Add a COALESCE around the max, that supplies Jan 1900 date if there is no max date (hence max returns null)

Comment: That ^ and I think using `order by` clause for `date_time` column is needed here.

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks, I'm not really familiar with Mysql. Would `> ALL` work equally well?

Comment: @stack why order if you're only interested in max value?

Comment: @JiriTousek something like `COALESCE(max(date_time), from_unixtime(0))` and remove the last sentence of your answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain it's a superb idea to implement this logic in the database - you seem to be looking for a query that will only insert the message A writes if they have not contacted B more than twice already but that sort of logic would be better off in the front end app. To this end, you'd be better off with a couple of queries:

```
Select count(*) from contact where sender_id = A and date_time > unix_timestamp(curdate())
```

And deny the message send if it is >= 4

Run JiriTousek's query and deny the send if it is >= 2

By deny send, I mean alter the front end so messaging is impossible so they don't waste their lives typing messages that can never send. Doing this blocking upon insert is kinda too late for that